# Laravel custom artisan command won't run without optimize:clear

Tags: php, laravel, queue

The problem sounds strange, I don't know how it appeared, everything on the server worked well.

I have a complex algorithm that processes a couple of thousand entries in the database every minute and updates them. It runs in about 10-15 seconds.

#### How I am runing this

1. On the server in cron every minute I call `php artisan schedule:run`
2. `App/Console/Kernel.php` contains the following code:

```php
// Every minute update mining data for every rig
$schedule->command('mining:run')->everyMinute();

// THIS! Without this cache clearing, the queues stop being called at all.
$schedule->command('optimize:clear')->everyMinute();

// Restart queue every day
$schedule->command('queue:restart')->cron('0 0 * * *');

// Configure running queues
$schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3')
  ->cron('* * * * *')
  ->withoutOverlapping();
```

3. `App/Console/Commands` contains `MiningRunCommand.php` which calls `MiningRunJob::dispatch()`
4. In the job I have 2 logs on the start and end of the algorithm, and between them the algorithm itself, which processes, let me remind you, several thousand records in the database, **which worked normally 2 days ago 5+ months**.

So, in my logs earlier, every minute `start` was displayed and then `end`; the algorithm started to run and then finished. Everything was fine.

But 2 days ago it just stopped working. I did something, restarted the queues 200 times, cleared the cache, etc., it seemed to work after I started calling `optimize:clear` every minute. This is a very bad practice. But now, *without errors* in the logs, I see the following picture: `start start start end start end start start end`.

That is, some of the runs of the algorithm are completed, and some are not (`start` is but `end` is not). And there are no errors, including in failed jobs.

Suggest what might have happened and how to fix it. Why do queues not work without cleaning?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is happening, but `optimize:clear` just cleans everything: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e2a32f2c172a97966a8390f7387d57b50fed20bc/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeClearCommand.php#L30-L44

I am thinking you have an issue with how you are running the queues. Instead of using:

```php
// Restart queue every day
$schedule->command('queue:restart')->cron('0 0 * * *');

// Configure running queues
$schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3')
  ->cron('* * * * *')
  ->withoutOverlapping();
```

First, do not restart the queues just because you want. Second, use a supervisor to keep track of the queues. The Laravel documentation explicity tells you how to achieve this: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#supervisor-configuration so please, do follow it and implement it.

Remember to remove too:

```php
// THIS! Without this cache clearing, the queues stop being called at all.
$schedule->command('optimize:clear')->everyMinute();
```

The last thing you can do is share the command code, and check GIT again and tell us what change you have done before it started failing

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I don't have supervisor on my shared hosting with isp manager. And i haven't changed any code on my server for 2 weeks